Moving from an input field to an autosuggest list in a child compnent with arrow keys in VueJS
I would like to be able to move focus from the input field in the parent component to the autosuggest list in a child component using the arrow down key.
I cannot get this to work. Tabbing works fine. If i use the this.$refs.suggestionButtons[0].focus(); in mounted the focus moves as soon as the autosuggest opens. I dont want this though. I only want the focus to be on the auto suggest when the arrow down key is clicked
Can anyone help with this please?
Component one (with input)
<input
    class="form-control form-control-lg"
    type="text"
    v-on:keyup="autoSuggest"
    v-model="search_input"
    placeholder="Enter a keyword"
    autocomplete="off"
    id="search"
    v-on:keyup.enter="showandSubmit"
  />
  <CourseAutoSuggest
    id="autoSuggestInput"
    ref="autocomplete"
    v-if="
      search_input.length > 1 && suggestions.length > 0
    "
    :suggestions="suggestions"
    :selected="selectedIndex"
    v-on:suggest-click="autoSuggestQuery"
    @close-dropdown="closeDropdown"
  />
</div>

Component Two (autosuggest)
<template>
     <div v-if="showSuggestions" class="search-auto-suggest col-8 col-md-12">
       <ul ref="suggestionsList">
         <li v-for="(suggestion, index) in suggestions" :key="suggestion">
           <button
             ref="suggestionButtons"
             @click="$emit('suggest-click', suggestion)"
             @keyup.enter="$emit('suggest-click', suggestion)"
             @keydown.arrow-up.prevent="moveFocusUp(index)"
             @keydown.arrow-down.prevent="moveFocusDown(index)"
            type="button"
            :aria-selected="selectedIndex === index ? 'true' : 'false'"
             >
          {{ suggestion }}
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    suggestions: Array,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedIndex: null,
      showSuggestions: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    moveFocusUp(index) {
      if (index > 0) {
        this.selectedIndex = index - 1;
        this.$refs.suggestionButtons[this.selectedIndex].focus();
      }
    },

    moveFocusDown(index) {
      if (index < this.suggestions.length - 1) {
        this.selectedIndex = index + 1;
        this.$refs.suggestionButtons[this.selectedIndex].focus();
      }
    },

    closeList(event) {
      if (event.key === "Escape") {
        this.showSuggestions = false;
        this.$emit("close-list");
      }
    },

    // focusInput() {
    //   this.$emit('focus-input');
    // }
  },
  mounted() {
    // Set initial focus
    // this.$refs.suggestionButtons[0].focus();

    // Listen for keydown events to close the list
    this.$el.addEventListener("keydown", this.closeList);
  },

  beforeUnmount() {
    this.$el.removeEventListener("keydown", this.closeList);
  },
};
</script>


Do not use eventListener, you have it in the realm of Vue here. I am not sure to fully understand the relationship between the child and the parent here but maybe try to have a button first, that focus your field once clicked. Also focus doesn't need to be "moved", it's baked into your browser. Can you maybe provide a [repro]?
